# Hide PayPal Button

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, paypal

I am trying to hide a PayPal button depending on the state of my switch. At the moment, once the paypal button gets rendered, it always stays there. Regardless of whether the switch gets set back to credit card

Here is the switch:

```
<p class="heading">Payment Method</p>
      <div class="frame flex-row flex-center">
        <button
          class="flex-column flex-center"
          (click)="paymentMethod = 'creditCard'; dismountPaypal()"
          [ngClass]="
            paymentMethod == 'creditCard' ? 'type-btn-active' : 'type-btn'
          "
        >
          Debit/Credit Card
        </button>
        <button
          class="flex-column flex-center"
          (click)="paymentMethod = 'paypal'; renderPaypal()"
          [ngClass]="paymentMethod == 'paypal' ? 'type-btn-active' : 'type-btn'"
        >
          PayPal
        </button>
      </div>
```

and here is the button itself:

```
 <div>
      <div #paypalRef></div>
    </div>
```

on my component.ts file I've got this to render the button, this function gets called when paypal gets clicked in the switch:

```
 @ViewChild("paypalRef", { static: true }) private paypalRef: ElementRef;
  renderPaypal() {
    if (this.paypalButtonRendered != true) {
      window.paypal
        .Buttons({
          style: {
            layout: "horizontal",
            color: "white",
          },
        })
        .render(this.paypalRef.nativeElement);
    }
    this.paypalButtonRendered = true;
  }
```

I've tried using ngIf on the parent div component and the div of the button itself. This just results in the button never being displayed. I've also tried using [ngClass] snd setting a CSS style to display none if the payment method is credit card, but this also doesn't work. I'm kind of at a loss right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use *ngIf and bind it with a boolean variable.

Answer (score 1):

Add the style `display: none;` to the button you don't want rendered, based on the paymentMethod condition.

Comment: Single line answers are preferred in the comment section.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to comment, but thanks for the note. I'll take that advice to account when I get the privilege!

Comment: Oops, my bad. You should have enough points now :D